# Skip specified tags when converting tags to htmlentities

Tags: php, html

Code

```
$string="<big>Like this,</big><b>This is </b><i>Mountain picture</i><var>I love it/var>";
$strconverted=htmlentities($string);
```

> I want to convert all tags to html entities but leave **b**,*i* tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP htmlentities allow <b> and <i> only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038236/php-htmlentities-allow-b-and-i-only)

Comment: @Waqas And what happens if I open the developer tools or FireBug and simply remove that `display: none`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why exactly do you use htmlentities? If only to strip html tags, then you can use `strip_tags()`:

`strip_tags( $string, '<b><i>' )`;

Answer (score 1):

After calling `htmlentities()`, you can convert those tags back to real tags:

```
$strconverted = str_replace(array('&lt;b&gt;', '&lt;/b&gt;', '&lt;i&gt;', '&lt;/i&gt;'), array('<b>', '</b>', '<i>', '</i>'), $strconverted);
```

So your code would look like this:

```
$string="<big>Like this,</big><b>This is </b><i>Mountain picture</i><var>I love it/var>";
$strconverted=htmlentities($string);

$strconverted = str_replace(array('&lt;b&gt;', '&lt;/b&gt;', '&lt;i&gt;', '&lt;/i&gt;'), array('<b>', '</b>', '<i>', '</i>'), $strconverted);
```